# Command Line Interface

Tags: java, консоль

Доброе время суток уважаемые пользователи!

Пишу консольную программу на java, и встал впорос как организовать меню программы, что бы было удобно пользоваться, и вот в интернете нашёл отличный пример (рисунок 1, 2).

[Рисунок 1](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=f785eb5aaa2d710052567b3a386c663e)

[Рисунок 2](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=2fcdbb8affb792672434265327fbc131)

Вопрос собственно вот в чём, что нужно для того что бы реализовать подобный интерфейс на Java? Буду очень благодарен за помощ. Так как в интернете я не нашёл информации.

Answer (score 3):

Плохо искали, стало быть. Первое, что нашлось про простейшему запросу в гугл:

- [JCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/)
- [Lanterna](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/)